# Passing string parameters to js function in onchange

Tags: javascript, html, smarty, onchange

I am trying to reuse a javascript function which I call in an option selection. In order to reuse it, I need to pass txt parameters to it, so the function can identify where it should e.g. draw the chart or what option was selected
I tried  setting the parameters in "
Its probably something simple but I really tried the search first...
According to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function2), the syntax is correct, no?

```
<select id="product_by_season" onchange="drawChart('product_by_season', 'donut-chart-season-chart', 'seasonchannelselect')" > 
[{foreach from=$productcount item=count name=season key=key}]
```

function:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load("current", {
          packages: ["corechart"]
        });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart(optionselect, chartvisual, maxcount ) {
            console.log(optionselect);
            console.log(chartvisual);
            console.log(maxcount);
            var listbox = document.getElementById(optionselect);
```

Console output:

```
undefined index.php:564:4
undefined index.php:565:4
undefined index.php:565:4
TypeError: listbox is null
```

Comment: Yes, that is the correct syntax. But are you getting the console output when you actually change a value in the `select`? Because you have also registered that function in `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);`, and does that one pass all parameters? If not, the log output is probably from when the Google Chart calls the function.

Comment: Ah ok, only when I render, even so I set "option selected" for the first index in the foreach. When I change the option it is rendering correctly and passing the params. So I need to call the fnc also when its rendering... onload and onloadstart are not working

Comment: Do you have more than that one `select`, or is it only that one on the page that calls the method?

Comment: yes, I want to have more then one, thats why I was trying to it. I could of course copy paster and rename the function. But I guess thats not in nice. you answer was correct. I changed the order, of the google chart and the function and it wokred at least only when selecting and not when rendered. This is making me problems. I also need to give a smarty variable, which I also am not able to sumbit to this js function. So I am currently working on something else ^^ till I have time again for this